# With CSS change siblings state on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, siblings

**Simple Explanation:** I want to change a siblings border color if the element is the the last element of this div.

**More In depth**

**Structure**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div class="grand-child"></div>
        <div class="grand-child"></div>
        <div class="grand-child"></div>
        <div class="grand-child"></div>
        <div class="grand-child"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="sibling"></div>
</div>
```

If you hover over the last grand-child in the child div, I need the siblings border color to change.

Comment: The condition of the hover having to be a specific child of  `#child`, rather than `#child` itself, means this impossible with CSS alone, as there is no parent selector. You will have to use JavaScript to implant this feature.

Comment: I was looking into this and I did not know if there was a convoluted way of doing it.  https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: No, even under CSS selectors module level 4, despite the presence of [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), this remains impossible (so far) because it seems `:has()` is omitted from the 'fast' selectors.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to talk to me about it, maybe something will come about later.  For me it was nothing important, just showmanship.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `:last-child` css selector? In your example, it could look something like this:

```css
div.grand-child:last-child:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div class="grand-child">First item</div>
    <div class="grand-child">Second item</div>
    <div class="grand-child">Third item</div>
    <div class="grand-child">Fourth item</div>
    <div class="grand-child">Fifth item</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sibling"></div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Guess you didn't read the question properly - *If you hover over the last grand-child in the child div, I* ***need the siblings border color to change.***

Comment: so if you hover over the 'Fifth item', the 'Fourth item''s border color changes?